# Application for slicing video

Tags: video, multimedia, video-editor

I'm using PiTiVi to edit a long lecture, and I'd like to split it into manageable chunks, then rearrange the pieces. However, I don't see a good way to do that in PiTiVi; apparently, I would have to cut a clip out, discard everything else, and save the clip for each clip I want to extract. Is there an Ubuntu application that's designed to slice videos into clips, or an application that can do it well?