# What is an easy video editor?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application for slicing video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12611/application-for-slicing-video)

I just need to cut some parts from a video that is too long. What would be a good (GUI) app to do that?

All the ones I tried (pitivi, kino) are way too complex for what I want to do

Thanks!