# Is there an application that will render the popular web video formats?

Tags: video-conversion

I am trying to convert video to the formats [commonly used for HTML5 embedding](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) — that is, MP4 (H264 + AAC), OGV (Theora + Vorbis) and WebM (VP8 + Vorbis). I would like to use a GUI application to do this as simply as possible.

I have the [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/) repository installed, but it doesn't seem to help. Avidemux is missing the H264 video encoder, and Handbrake only does MP4 (not the other two). How can I configure these apps under 11.10 for my purposes, or alternatively, what else is there?

Comment: You can try VLC, it will convert as you need. but using it for convert bunch of videos will make you tired

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this question: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532) may be helpful for your case. In this answer I talk about [Miksoft's Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm), but there are a few alternatives to this task which can easily be reached over the net.

Anyway, Mobile Media Converter will only work for 32 bit version OS's. And for both 32/64 bit version I suggest you to give a chance to

## **[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)**

[image]

## **[Transmaggedon](http://www.linuxrising.org/)**

[image]

## **[Transcoder](http://transcoder84.sourceforge.net/)**

[image]

## **[Arista Transcoder](http://www.transcoder.org/)**

[image]

And there are some other useful Transcoding Software, which includes Non Linear Editing Systems like those mentioned on the answers to this question: [What is an easy video editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58250/what-is-an-easy-video-editor/58266#58266) and command line using **[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)**. (as mentioned by @tomodachi)

Nevertheless, ***the trick*** in compression (in order to make the videos lighter when loaded to/from the server) isn't in the software itself but the way you make your videos.

You must pay special attention to the ***Audio and Video Bitrates***, which determines both the quality and file size for the resulting transcoded videos and remember that the higher bitrate will result in a higher quality but it will also drop "heavy" file sizes.

You should run as many tests as you need in order to feel comfortable with both the resulting quality and file size.

There is no a pre-defined set of parameters which will do always the same for your videos when you are trying to save something, let's say: quality and file size, or in the worst case: both them.

There is no such "magic codec" that will result in a better quality with small file sizes. Take in consideration that you could have a mpeg1 video file (VCD) with a high bitrate looking better than an mp4 video file with a lower bitrate.

***Additionally and only for your consideration:***

The [FileInfo.com webpage](http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/video) related to "Video Formats" provides an extensive and really comprehensive list of video formats, its available software which can be used to play each one and the "popularity".

You may also wish to take a look to the "[Digital Container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format)" and the table of "[Comparison of container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats)".

Good luck!

*- Parts of this answer were took from [Reduce avi size without losing too much quality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151493/reduce-avi-size-without-losing-too-much-quality/160177#160177)*

Answer (score 0):

Install `ffmpeg` from source! It might take a bit longer, but then you will get all the best possible coverage of supported formats.

Comment: I think I'll pass on hosing my package management...