# How To Capture Video

Tags: video

How to capture an online video stream and edit (convert into other formats, make a clip, etc.) it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: Please ask your second question in a new question.  A question on AskUbuntu should only be asking 1 thing.

Comment: Yeah! ask another question and expect it just to be closed because of "that was asked before". I strongly suggest you to run a search on this site for questions such as: "video editor", which will deliver lots of answers of which I recommend: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5911/video-editing-software-options and http://askubuntu.com/questions/58250/what-is-an-easy-video-editor. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can install some Firefox or Chrome plugin for doing that, such as [Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/).

Or, for Youtube an other popular websites, you can use [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/), wich works on the browser.

For the second question, I suggest you to create a new one. I hope it works to you!

Comment: Please remove your answer to the second part of the question.  The OP is required to put his second question in another question, so wait for that to be posted and answer the second part on that one instead.  Questions cannot contain two different questions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I suggest him to create a new question, not answering the second question.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry there, I misread your post, ;)

Answer (score 1):

To convert videos into different format, *handbrake* is a handy tool.

Answer (score 1):

I found "All video downloader" from the ubuntu software center(12.04 lts Precise Pangolin) a good program which has the following PROS:

1. Can download from a host of sites such as youtube, DM, Vimeo, etc.
2. Easy to use with a good UI.
3. Has  batch mode where you can copy-paste many video URLS  and will download one at a time.
4. Supports down load in many formats (FLV, MP4, MP4-HD,  etc) but always first downloads in flv first and then converts it to whatever format you had selected.

CONS :

1. A bit slower( compared to the ones I have in windows), if you want to download in any format other than FLV.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com Before answering a question you might want to check to see if it has been asked before and point the user towards that one. It saves the trouble of merging questions and answers later which can be messy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [**ClipGrab**](http://clipgrab.de/en). ClipGrab is a free downloader and converter for YouTube, Vimeo, Dailymotion and many other online video sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try Keepvid downloader which is free and safe to use. I used to get loads of videos from web via this tool. Though it sometimes may not handle some clips which depend on the situations.