# split video from mkv, avi, mp4

Tags: mp4, mkv, avi

I've a mkv video file and want to split some important scenes. Is there any tool in ubuntu to split them. I'm looking for GUI tool. any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application for slicing video](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12611/application-for-slicing-video)

Answer (score 3):

Avidemux can do this. Install it from - http://avidemux.sourceforge.net

[image: image of avidemux]

Answer (score 2):

[Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) 
fantastic video editor 
you can fined it in software center